# How to access a specific text inside a span in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id = "item_container">

<div class="price">
            <span class ="discounted">
                   "
                   $150
                   " 
                   </span> 
                    "$125 for 2 months" 
                   <br>
                "
                Handling Fee: $3.15
                "
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me or point me to the right direction on how to access the text "$125 for 2 months" using javascript?

I tried using querySelector but it will only get the $150 text.

```
var discounted_price = document.querySelector('#item_container > div.price > span').innerHTML;
console.log(discounted_price);
```

The code I used will not get the remaining text which i need.

Comment: im not sure why you expect to get more than the `span`. its in your selector.

Comment: I was also expecting to get "$150 $125 for 2 months Delivery Fee: $3.15" but it only returned $150.

So my code is already correct and there is no way to enhance it to target $125 for 2 months text only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the HTML is always like that, you can [query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) `.discounted` then transverse to the [next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).

Once you get there, you can get the [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) for that text node

```js
const discounted_price = document.querySelector('.discounted')
console.log(discounted_price.nextSibling.nodeValue);
```

```html
<div id="item_container">

  <div class="price">
    <span class="discounted">
                   "
                   $150
                   " 
                   </span> "$125 for 2 months"
    <br> " Handling Fee: $3.15 "
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The text you're looking for is not inside the `span`, instead it's the next sibling node of the span

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".discounted").nextSibling.textContent.trim();
console.log(text)
```

```html
<html>
<div id = "item_container">

<div class="price">
            <span class ="discounted">
                   "
                   $150
                   " 
                   </span> 
                    "$125 for 2 months" 
                   <br>
                "
                Handling Fee: $3.15
                "
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```